# How to move a rectangle in onDraw

Tags: android, touch-event

I have a problem that I can't solve.The problem is that I want to push a rectangle with another rectangle,I do it this way:

```
    public  boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){


    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touchX = event.getX();
        touchY = event.getY();          
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        dx = touchX - event.getX();
        dy = touchY - event.getY();            
        if(Math.abs(dy) > Math.abs(dx)){ 

            if(dy > 0){   //Direction UP   



                manFirstY = manFirstY - 50;
                manSecondY = manSecondY - 50;                    
                if(manFirstY < targetSecondY && manFirstX == targetFirstX){                     
                    targetFirstY = targetFirstY - 50;
                    targetSecondY = targetSecondY - 50;

                }

            }

            else if(dy < 0){    //Direction DOWN                                   
                manFirstY = manFirstY + 50;
                manSecondY = manSecondY + 50;                    
                if(manSecondY > targetFirstY && manFirstX == targetFirstX){                 
                    targetFirstY = targetFirstY + 50;
                    targetSecondY = targetSecondY + 50;
                }

            }
        }
        else{
            if(dx > 0){     //Direction LEFT                 
                manFirstX = manFirstX - 50;
                manSecondX = manSecondX - 50;                  
                if(manFirstX < targetSecondX && manFirstY == targetFirstY){
                    targetFirstX = targetFirstX - 50;
                    targetSecondX = targetSecondX - 50;
                }

            }
            else if(dx < 0){     //Direction RIGHT                    
                manFirstX = manFirstX + 50;
                manSecondX = manSecondX + 50;                 
                if(manSecondX > targetFirstX && manFirstY == targetFirstY){
                    targetFirstX = targetFirstX +50;
                    targetSecondX = targetSecondX +50;
                }   
            }
        }          
}

return true;
```

}

but there's a problem.When I use this way it works but besides pushing it is carying the rect with it.I don't want the rect to carry another I just want to push it and when I want the rect to move away from the one that he pushes I just want to release it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that manFirstX/manSecondX/manFirstY/manSecondY are the left, right, upper and lower edges of the first rectangle and the same with target for the second rectangle, you should try to examine your code with an example!

If the first rectangle is on the right side of the second one, `manSecondX` will always be larger than `targetSecondX`. If you move to the right and your first rectangle is on the right side of the second one, your condition `if(manSecondX > targetFirstX && manFirstY == targetFirstY)` will be always be true!

So my advise is to simply add a condition e.g.

```
public  boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

switch(event.getAction()){
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    touchX = event.getX();
    touchY = event.getY();          
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    dx = touchX - event.getX();
    dy = touchY - event.getY();            
    if(Math.abs(dy) > Math.abs(dx)){ 

        if(dy > 0){   //Direction UP   



            manFirstY = manFirstY - 50;
            manSecondY = manSecondY - 50;                    
            if(targetFirstY < manSecondY && manFirstY < targetSecondY && manFirstX == targetFirstX){                     
                targetFirstY = targetFirstY - 50;
                targetSecondY = targetSecondY - 50;

            }

        }

        else if(dy < 0){    //Direction DOWN                                   
            manFirstY = manFirstY + 50;
            manSecondY = manSecondY + 50;                    
            if(targetSecondY > manFirstY && manSecondY > targetFirstY && manFirstX == targetFirstX){                 
                targetFirstY = targetFirstY + 50;
                targetSecondY = targetSecondY + 50;
            }

        }
    }
    else{
        if(dx > 0){     //Direction LEFT                 
            manFirstX = manFirstX - 50;
            manSecondX = manSecondX - 50;                  
            if(targetFirstX < manSecondX && manFirstX < targetSecondX && manFirstY == targetFirstY){
                targetFirstX = targetFirstX - 50;
                targetSecondX = targetSecondX - 50;
            }

        }
        else if(dx < 0){     //Direction RIGHT                    
            manFirstX = manFirstX + 50;
            manSecondX = manSecondX + 50;                 
            if(targetSecondX > manFirstX && manSecondX > targetFirstX && manFirstY == targetFirstY){
                targetFirstX = targetFirstX +50;
                targetSecondX = targetSecondX +50;
            }   
        }
    }          
}

return true;
```

This hopefully works!